# Intellij scala worksheet can't find project classes

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am unable to get a scala worksheet to find any of my project classes when using Intellij. I have added the new scala worksheet to the `src` directory of my project as instructed [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Working+with+Scala+Worksheet). However whenever I try to run the worksheet I get the following error

```
Error:(5, 27) not found: type Order
    trait LimitOrder extends Order {
                     ^
```

The `Order` trait is defined in a file included in `src/main/scala`. I even tried putting the scala worksheet in the `src/main/scala` and it still fails to find the `Order` trait.

It appears that the problem goes away if either:

1. I open an external `sbt-console` in my project directory. Opening the `sbt-console` automatically compiles the project sources. Then return to Intellij and re-run the worksheet.
2. I manually compile the source inside Intellij prior to trying to run the worksheet.

I was under the impression that the worksheet was being compiled on the fly every time I re-run it and thus manually compiling it should be un-necessary. Is this incorrect?

Comment: don't think Scala worksheet is supposed to work that way

Comment: As I mentioned I am a scala newbie. How exactly is the scala worksheet supposed to work?

Comment: Are you able to look up the Order class with ctrl-n (search for class)? WarFox: It works that way on my machine

Comment: Yes I can find the classes via search as you describe. The worksheet doesn't show any errors (i.e., has green box in top right-hand corner) until I try to run the worksheet at which point I get the above compile-error.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As mentioned in this [discussion thread](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2012/12/04/scala-worksheet/), in order for a worksheet to find changes to your source classes you need to manually check the "Make project" box which will force a recompile of sources prior to running the worksheet.

Comment: THANK YOU, this helped me finally

Comment: I marked "Make project" and it all seemed to work.. except that when I change something in the imported classes the change is not there.
For example if I change a method signature the worksheet is ok (it also autocompletes the method's name) but at runtime I get: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Comment: @Ena did you find solution for that?

Comment: @Ena - I had this problem too - there a fix described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46822166/intellij-scala-worksheet-dont-pick-up-code-changes-without-restart)

Comment: @notgiorgi - see my comment above