# Unselecting "Run worksheet in the compiler process" causes source file not to be found

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

When I select File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Scala -> Worksheet (tab) . Unselect "Run worksheet in the compiler process". I get an error as follows

```
Error:source file '/home/username' could not be found
```

I needed to untick the option to fix a the problem whereby  Scala Worksheets aren't registering my changes after I change my source code.  The following posts asked me to untick that checkbox.  I'm using Ubuntu Debian if that is relevant.

Scala worksheets are not picking up my changes without a restart so I tried

[Intellij scala worksheet can't find project classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598480/intellij-scala-worksheet-cant-find-project-classes)

and

[IntelliJ: Scala worksheet don't pick up code changes without restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46822166/intellij-scala-worksheet-dont-pick-up-code-changes-without-restart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug, please vote on the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-14694